# Hide multiple table rows by class

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've got a pretty large table of companies, these companies can have a daughter, these are listed underneath them. I want to be able to toggle each 'section' of daughters per company.

If a company has daughters, I added a `<span class="image">` to each `<td>` which displays a image. If you click on the image, the rows of the daughters will be toggled.

The layout looks like this:

```
 <tr>
     <td><span class="image"></span>
     <td>Company</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Company</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Company</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Company</td></tr>
 <tr>
     <td><span class="image"></span>
     <td>Company</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>
 <tr class="company_daughter"><td>!data</td></tr>

 etc
```

So far I came up with this:

```
$('.image').click(function(){ 
    var closest = $(this).closest('tr')
    $('tr.company_daughter').each(function(){
            closest.hide();
        }
    );
});
```

Each company should only display her own daughters

However I seem not to be able to get the 'section' problem right.

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to use `nextUntil()`

Comment: are you able to change the HTML or are you stuck with it?  Can you add a `data-companyid` attribute to each company, and a `data-parent-companyid` to each daughter?  That would make your select way easier.

Comment: @orzechowskid I could add that.

Comment: ooh.  `nextUntil()` would work too.  But using ids or `data-` attributes might make your HTML a little more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should what you want;

```
$('.image').click(function(){ 
    // get the clicked company row
    var closest = $(this).closest('tr');
    //give main company class "company"
    closest.nextUntil("tr.company").each(function(){
            //Every this means tr.company_daughter
            $(this).toggle();
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work, it will hide all `company_daughter` after that `.image` has been clicked:

```
$(".image").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil("tr:not(.company_daughter)").toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rj5Ac/2/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, though currently untested:

```
$('.image').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(".image")').toggle();
});
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).